# Editing TFS2010 Build Definitions

Tags: tfs

We're currently setting up a number of builds in TFS2010 for our various projects/solutions.

We have a large number where the structure and paths, etc. are essentially the same, but one word may change (for example, using all Integration workspaces versus our Trunk workspaces).

In TFS2008, I would simply edit the XML directly and do some creative search and replace or some magic in textpad before saving the file.  However, I do not see any immediate way of doing this in TFS2010 - so I'm stuck slogging through the build definition UI.

I know, in doing a SQL Trace, that all of this ends up as XML - so is there a way to directly access this XML for hand-editing vs. being forced to do all changes through the front-end?

Thanks!

**Edit for additional clarity**

I have the Power Tools installed, etc. and can clone my builds - but my editing options are still limited to the UI, so if I have a large number of workspace path changes I have to do them by hand (one at a time).

My goal is to be able to directly edit the XAML for a specific build definition so I can do a clone, open the XAML, and then do a search/replace in bulk.

Comment: Did you eventually find any decent solution to this? I want to search all our build definitions for a specific agent tag. Opening them one by one is cumbersome to say the least.

Comment: Never mind. By executing `SELECT ProcessParameters FROM Tfs_ProjectCollection.dbo.tbl_BuildDefinition`, I got all the information I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and install the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f). You can also get them through the Visual Studio Extension Gallery. After installing, you can right click on a Build Definition in Team Explorer and select the Clone Build Definition command (added by the Power Tools installation) to make a copy of an existing build definition. Then you can tweak it appropriately for another branch, etc.

Comment: Yep, I've been doing that- but the problem is that while I can clone things, etc. if I have to change, say, twenty workspaces from integration to trunk I am stuck doing it one by one in the UI.  Was hoping there was a way to get directly to the XAML for a specific build so I can do a search/replace.

Comment: @Bob: why are you having to change these things? Shouldn't you be setting up separate team projects for the different branches?

Comment: @Bob, one handy tip I can offer is that, in the workspace tab of the build definition editor, you can select all of the mappings and use Ctrl+C to copy them to the clipboard. Then, you can paste them into the text editor of your choice, do a search and replace, and then copy the updated mappings to the clipboard. Go back to the Workspace tab of the build definition editor, select all and paste.

Comment: We branch from trunk for development (then developers branch off of the integration branch).  We then forward integrate our changes.  We have checkpoints both at the integration level, and another when integration os forward integrated into trunk - so the build scripts for integration and trunk are essentially the same other than one piece of the file path.  Separate team projects would not make sense, since both branches are in fact just facets of the same project.

Comment: By the way, we are working on a power tool to facilitate bulk-updates to workspace mappings from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The following tool (VS Addin) will satisfy your requirement>

Community TFS Build Manager

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/16bafc63-0f20-4cc3-8b67-4e25d150102c

Answer (score 0):

The build definitions are all .xaml files now - they're WF4 workflows, and they're XML files.

---

Jim Lamb is right. The build *templates* are .xaml files now. The definitions are accessed through web services.

I'm about to experiment with a quick HTML form posting to `/tfs/_tfs_resources/Build/V3.0/BuildService.asmx/QueryBuildDefinitionsByUri`. I noticed when I clicked the build definition in Team Explorer that it has an associated URI:  `vstfs:///Build/Definition/2`. Stay tuned.

Comment: Where can I find the XAML for a specific build?  All I saw were more general ones when I poked around...

Comment: Under Build Definitions at the top of the team project.

Comment: The Workflow XAML files are generalized build process templates that can be used for a variety of build definitions. I don't think that's what you're looking for.